# Windows 8.1 login error after power cut "The object invoked has disconnected from its client"

Tags: windows-8.1, login

Earlier I had a power cut, possibly due to weather.
 My PC was powered on and logged in but locked at the time, and when I turned it back on later, trying to log in resulted in the error message **"The object invoked has disconnected from its client."**
 with the option only to try logging in again.
 I booted into Safe Mode and I can log in properly that way, but I'm suspecting a storage or memory failure. **What most likely happened? and how could I fix it, hopefully without restoring anything?**

Comment: Update: it was probably a new set of speakers I plugged into the wrong jack. Unplugged them, restarted the computer and everything worked fine.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept it as the answer that worked, this gives the site a working answer for this question should anybody have the same problem, you can also add more detail to the question giving a broader base for searches of similar questions, thankyou